# Mapping for the leader

Tags: key-bindings

I have taken the `.vimrc` from another guy. However, is `Leader` character is now `,`, and I am no longer able to modify it

`let mapleader = ","`

I'm trying to change it for the default leader with `let mapleader = "\"`, but it didn't work. Could anyone be able to tell me how to obtain the default mapping?

Comment: Does work if you restart Vim?

Comment: `I have taken the .vimrc from another guy` It has already been said on this site but really you shouldn't do that: you'll spend waaaay more time debugging things you don't need/you don't understand than creating your own vimrc which really fits your needs/

Comment: While I understand what @statox is saying, it is really common to learn `vim` because a coworker uses it any time they come to use your computer to help you with code. In that case I put my `~/.vim/vimrc` on their machine so that I can teach them. I'm sure that since 1998, many of them have had questions. Though to help them I always use long-form everything.

Answer (score 3):

To get the default behaviour, the best way would be simply remove that setting from `.vimrc`. But it's also possible to set that in `.vimrc` by any of the following:

```
let mapleader = "\\"
```

or

```
let mapleader = '\'
```

Using double quote requires escaping special characters. And because `\` is a special character used to escape others, it has to be escaped as well.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you set the leader before using any mappings which involve the leader. When you use the leader in a mapping you're not saying "use whatever the leader is, which I might have defined now, or I might define later on in this vimrc file" you're saying "use whatever the leader is currently set to right now".